# Adding Mailchimp members as "Not-Subscribed" through API

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

In this article: https://mailchimp.com/help/about-your-contacts/ it lists the status options as:

1. Subscribed
2. Unsubscribed
3. Not-Subscribed
4. Cleaned

By passing in "subscribed" or "unsubscribed" as the status, this will update, however I cannot find a valid value to pass in for people who are Not-Subscribed.

"Pending" puts them into a pending state which triggers an email to be sent to the user to approve. The API doesn't allow you to leave it blank.

Is there a way to do this? In an ideal world, I want to allow the system calling the API to set subscribe/unsubscribe after further action from the user, while still initially adding them into the contacts list.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Mailchimp API documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/update-list-member/), these are the only possible values for a subscriber's current status:

`"subscribed"`
`"unsubscribed"`
`"cleaned"`
`"pending"`

I suggest trying `null` if possible, or leaving the value empty as `status=` to see if that works. Otherwise, documentation is law.

Edit:
Untested, but you could also try passing an empty value using `%02%03` as the contents of the value, given that `%02` denotes the start of an ASCII character and `%03` denotes the end of an ASCII Character. Success would depend on whether the Mailchimp server would allow it.

Comment: Leaving the status blank or using "%02%03" does not work.